# Ignore MySQL query if table is locked

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have a cronjob that executes a MySQL query every few minutes, summarizing a large amount of rows in a MyISAM table. However, if this table is locked for a few minutes then these summary queries will pile up, so that even when the table is finally available again they will block it for a long time.

None of these queries are essential, so I am happy with them failing from time to time. Thus, I would prefer it if these queries just failed if the table is blocked for more than a second or two.

Is there a way to submit a query to MySQL that automatically gets killed if it waits for more than a few seconds for the table lock? Can I somehow mark the query as unimportant?

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if a table is locked by looking at the open tables, using the command:

`show open tables;`

If you see your table locked, you can cancel the query before making it. Docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-open-tables.html).

It also looks like 5.7 is going to implement SELECT timeouts properly: http://mysqlserverteam.com/server-side-select-statement-timeouts/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`pt-kill`](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-kill.html) (Percona Toolkit). You could add an identifiable comment to your cron queries to help target the queries if required. It is worth using the `--sentinel` flag to allow you to safely cause `pt-kill` to exit.

Also, if you add locking to the cron job then you would prevent pile-ups.

Answer (score 0):

Would a better method be to just have one of these queries run? This would stop the piling up from happening. Make some sort of semafore (even a file-type flag) to see if there is some query already waiting, and if so, do'nt start another).

As you say, it isn't bad if some aren't run, and this might be easier to implement.